# DNN Change Title for Setting page

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Here is another one for helping hand's.Its about Dnn's Setting page. I want to change  the   tab   Title.is there any easy solution for that i search about it ; but i come up with empty hands.
[image: Change Title Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically handled by your RESX file (language resources) for Settings.ascx

the string you need is ControlTitle_settings.Text

and can be found in /app_localresources/settings.ascx.resx within your module directory.

You can see an example at https://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/App_LocalResources/Settings.ascx.resx

If you don't have the SOURCE for the module you can use the DNN Language Editor, admin/languages, and find the module in the folder list on the left.

Comment: thank you Chris. but i have multiple setting pages so where i need to change title for other setting pages or i need to add multiple keys in same resx file.

Comment: The Tab title is specific to the Settings control being loaded.